# How to shorten the length of the border-bottom? In html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a div container (bootstrap.min.css thing). And the div has another class named divborder. The border-bottom of the divborder is long, how can I cut it? Or maybe shorten its length? 
Sample code:

```css
.divborder {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #C6C4C5;
  /*what should i put here to shorten this border-bottom?*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container divborder">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    some img
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    some texts
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be better to provide an example of the intended end result, I don't think you've fully grasped the concept of CSS borders yet and how they apply, so they're probably *not the solution you're looking for*.

Comment: I cant post a picture here because im a newbie :( but here is the link of example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs81n.jpg
the border-bottom appears shorter here, how to do this?

Comment: That's probably not a border property, more likely a `pseudo-element` - Paulie_D should have you covered with his answer.

Comment: you may consider margin on the element that has border to control the length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the actual **length** of the border.

You'd need to use a positioned pseudo-element.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  top: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the length of the border bottom, which has been described in this blog post very well. https://www.steckinsights.com/shorten-length-border-bottom-pure-css/

```
 .page-title:after {
    content: ""; /* This is necessary for the pseudo element to work. */ 
    display: block; /* This will put the pseudo element on its own line. */
    margin: 0 auto; /* This will center the border. */
    width: 50%; /* Change this to whatever width you want. */
    padding-top: 20px; /* This creates some space between the element and the border. */
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; /* This creates the border. Replace black with whatever color you want. */
}
```